# How to implement models for Branch wise permission management in DJango?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-permissions

I was trying to implement CRM application in Django. The company will have multiple branches, and staff also work for one more branches in different roles. For example, they may work in branch-A as a sales manager and branch -b as  a Branch Manager, I was trying to implement that by Django Group and Permission, But that is not efficient way, it will be very help full if somebody help me to do this.Please see my code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from branch.models import Branch
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group 
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class BranchRole(models.Model):
    branch_code=models.ForeignKey(Branch,on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_constraint=False,related_name='in_roles')
    role=models.ForeignKey(Group)

    

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
    roles=models.ManyToManyField(BranchRole,related_name='holding_staffs')


    
class Staff(User):
    is_staff=1
    staff_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an another custom Class, you can create a class called position which holds data about branch and position at the branch. Each record can be different for each branch and each position. So you can use this this position using ManyToOne join with user.

Comment: Okey, Thanks for the reply. I think i was using same way. I had created staff by extends user, I have already created   role field in User. As you said branch role will hold position and branch.  roles=models.ManyToManyField(BranchRole,related_name='holding_staffs'). But i dont think its right way to solve this.

Comment: I don't think it needs to extend User. Also if you need many to many join, you can create an intermediate class which holds records about both user and roles.